# Не полчается пройти авторизацию через Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Не могу авторизоваться с помощью Jsoup для дальнейшего парсинга. 
В чем проблема можете подсказать? Ниже предоставлен код и HTTP запрос.

Код POST  запроса.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://e1.wrent.seejeju.com/login.aspx")
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .execute();

response = Jsoup.connect("https://e1.wrent.seejeju.com/login.aspx")
    .referrer("https://e1.wrent.seejeju.com/login.aspx")
    .data("txtCompanyName", "예스렌트카")
    .data("txtUserID", "логин")
    .data("txtUserPW", "пароль")
    .data("btnLogin", "로그인")
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .execute();
```

HTTP запрос

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Вписал все значения из Form Data

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/356655)

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, вроде как является - указал не все необходимые поля, поэтому и не работало. К тому же, это автор вопроса.